# Как из сдвига в секундах от UTC получть часовой пояс?

Tags: python, python-3.x, openweathermap

От OpenWeatherMap API приходит смещение в секундах:

```
('timezone': 7200)
```

Как из этого получить часовой пояс?

Comment: Одному и тому же сдвигу могут соответствовать несколько разных часовых поясов

Comment: @andreymal
В редких случаях

Comment: смотря что подразумевается под «часовым поясом», если элемент в tzdatabase, то однозначно определить это почти ни как нельзя... если смещение в часах — то можно просто разделить на `3600`...

Comment: @Fat-Zer В апи написано это и все timezone Shift in seconds from UTC

Comment: @12345, это понятно, но что именно ты подразумеваешь под понятием «часовой пояс», который хочешь из этого получить?

Comment: @Fat-Zer К примеру мой часовой пояс +03:00 GTM - вот это я и хочу получить

Comment: Формально это не часовой пояс, а то же самое смещение, просто записанное в другом формате

Comment: @andreymal Так как его получить??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если не выёживаться по поводу того, «что такое часовой пояс» и «в чём священная разница между UTC и GMT», то можно как-то так:

```
from datetime import timezone,timedelta
print(timezone(timedelta(seconds=7200))) # UTC+02:00
```

Если обязательно нужен именно формат вида `+03:00 GMT`, то скорей всего придётся колхозить через форматирование:

```
seconds=7200
print("{:+03d}:{:02d} GMT".format(seconds//3600, seconds%3600//60)) # +02:00 GMT
```

Comment: Спасибо мне достаточно первого варианта.